# the time taken to go up/down using either of the escalators when they are switched off given the following conditions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> There are two identical escalators,one is ascending and the other is descending.A Person took 90s to go up using descending escalators and 18s to go up using the escalating escalator.Both times working at the same speed.If the speed of the two escalators is the same,then the time taken to go up/down using either of the escalators when they are switched off is

MyApproach:

speed of both escalators are same

Therefore,

D1/$90$=D2/$18$  D1,D2 are their respective distance.

I can solve upto this only.

> Can Anyone guide me how to approach this problem?